# Expansion of a wavefunction of a two-particle system in one dimension in an arbitrary basis without operations associated with the tensor product

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction

In Shankar's Principle of Quantum Mechanics, Section 10.1, part **The Direct Product Revisited** (he calls tensor products direct products), he attempts to show that a two-particle state space is the tensor product of two one-particle state space. He begins by letting $\Omega^{(1)}_1$ be an operator on the state space $\Bbb V_1$ of a particle in one dimension, whose nondegenerate eigenfunctions $\psi_{\omega_1}(x_1)$ form a complete basis, and similarly, letting $\psi_{\omega_2}(x_2)$ form a basis for the state space $\Bbb V_2$ of a second particle. He then states that if a function $\psi(x_1,x_2)$ that represents the abstract vector $|\psi\rangle$ from the state space $\Bbb V_{1\otimes2}$ of a system consisting of both particles has $x_1$ fixed at some value $\bar x_1$, then $\psi$ becomes a function of $x_2$ alone and may be expanded as $$\psi(\bar x_1,x_2)=\sum_{\omega_2}C_{\omega_2}(\bar x_1)\psi_{\omega_2}(x_2)\tag{1}\label{e1}$$ where $$C_{\omega_2}(\bar x_1)=\sum_{\omega_1}C_{\omega_1\omega_2}\psi_{\omega_1}(\bar x_1)\tag{2}\label{e2}$$ Substituting \eqref{e2} into \eqref{e1} and dropping the bar on $\bar x_1$, the author states that the resulting expansion $$\psi(x_1,x_2)=\sum_{\omega_1}\sum_{\omega_2}C_{\omega_1\omega_2}\psi_{\omega_1}(x_1)\psi_{\omega_2}(x_2)\tag{3}\label{e3}$$ imply that $\Bbb V_{1\otimes2}=\Bbb V_1\otimes\Bbb V_2$ for $\psi_{\omega_1}(x_1)\times\psi_{\omega_2}(x_2)$ is the same as the inner product between $|x_1\rangle\otimes|x_2\rangle$ ($|x_1\rangle$ and $|x_2\rangle$ are the position basis vectors of $\Bbb V_1$ and $\Bbb V_2$ respectively) and $|\omega_1\rangle\otimes|\omega_2\rangle$ ($|\omega_1\rangle$ and $|\omega_2\rangle$ are the basis eigenvectors of $\Omega_1$ on $\Bbb V_1$ and $\Omega_2$ on $\Bbb V_2$ respectively).
 **Question**: How does \eqref{e1} follow from fixing $x_1$ in $\psi(x_1,x_2)$ as $\bar x_1$? Using the simultaneous eigenbasis $|\omega_1\omega_2\rangle$ of the operators $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ on $\Bbb V_{1\otimes2}$, $$\psi(\bar x_1,x_2)=\langle\bar x_1x_2|\psi\rangle=\sum_{\omega_1}\sum_{\omega_2}\langle\omega_1\omega_2|\psi\rangle\langle\bar x_1x_2|\omega_1\omega_2\rangle=\sum_{\omega_1}\sum_{\omega_2}\langle\omega_1\omega_2|\psi\rangle\psi_{\omega_1\omega_2}(\bar x_1,x_2).\tag{4}\label{e4}$$If the author intends $C_{\omega_1\omega_2}$ to mean $\langle\omega_1\omega_2|\psi\rangle$, what is the reason (besides the tensor product since he is trying to show that $\Bbb V_{1\otimes2}=\Bbb V_1\otimes\Bbb V_2$) for $\psi_{\omega_1\omega_2}(\bar x_1,x_2)=\psi_{\omega_1}(\bar x_1)\psi_{\omega_2}(x_2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we fix $x_1 = \bar{x}_1$, the function $\psi(\bar{x}_1, x_2)$ describes a valid state of the second particle, so can be decomposed with respect to the eigenbasis $\psi_{\omega_2}(x_2)$. The coefficients in this decomposition depend on the value $\bar{x}_1$, and denoting these coefficients by $C_{\omega_2}(\bar{x}_1)$ we get (1).

Comment: Why are the coefficients equal to the sum in Equation (2)?

Comment: Because $C_{\omega_2}(x_1)$ are now functions in the state space of the first variable and can be decomposed with respect to the eigenbasis $\psi_{\omega_1}(x_1)$.

Comment: Why should $C_{\omega_2}(x_1)$ be in the state space of the first variable? Aren't the coefficients, when absolute squared, just the probabilities of a measurement of the observable corresponding to $\Omega_1^{(1)}$ yielding each eigenvalue?

Comment: $\psi_{\omega_1}$ is a basis, we can decompose any function with respect to it.

Comment: You can also think like this: for every fixed $\omega_2$ we have $\int \psi_{\omega_2}^*(x_2)\psi(x_1, \bar{x}_2) d\bar{x}_2 = \sum_{\omega'_2} C_{\omega'_2}(x_1) \int \psi_{\omega_2}^*(\bar{x}_2)\psi_{\omega'_2}(\bar{x}_2) d\bar{x}_2 = C_{\omega_2}(x_1)$, so $C_{\omega_2}(x_1)$ is a combination of all $\psi(x_1, \bar{x}_2)$, which are states of the first particle, so lies in the state space $\mathbb{V}_1$

Comment: -How abut this as the reason for Equation 2?:- $\psi(x_1,x_2)=\sum_{\omega_1}\sum_{\omega_2}\langle x_1x_2|\psi\rangle\langle x_1x_2|\omega_1\omega_2\rangle=\sum_{\omega_1}\sum_{\omega_2}C_{\omega_1\omega_2}\psi_{\omega_1\omega_2}(x_1,x_2)$. When $x_1=\bar x_1$, $\psi=\sum_{\omega_1}\sum_{\omega_2}C_{\omega_1\omega_2}\psi_{\omega_1\omega_2}(\bar x_1,x_2)=\sum_{\omega_2}A_{\omega_2}(\bar x_1)\psi_{\omega_2}(x_2)$, where $A_{\omega_2}(\bar x_1)$ denotes the coefficients of expansion of $\psi(\bar x_1,x_2)$ in the basis $\psi_{\omega_2}(x_2)$, implies that (continued in the next comment)

Comment: $\psi_{\omega_1\omega_2}(\bar x_1,x_2)=f_{\omega_1}(\bar x_1)\psi_{\omega_2}(x_2)$ and $A_{\omega_2}(\bar x_1)=\sum_{\omega_1}C_{\omega_1\omega_2}f_{\omega_1}(\bar x_1)$, where $f_{\omega_1}$ is some function of $\bar x_1$. Dropping the bar on $\bar x_1$, now $\psi(x_1,x_2)= \sum_{\omega_1}\sum_{\omega_2}C_{\omega_1\omega_2}f_{\omega_1}(x_1)\psi_{\omega_2}(x_2)$. (continued in the next comment)

Comment: When $x_2$ is fixed at some value $\bar x_2$, $\psi=\sum_{\omega_1}\sum_{\omega_2}C_{\omega_1\omega_2}f_{\omega_1}(x_1)\psi_{\omega_2}(\bar x_2)=\sum_{\omega_1}B_{\omega_1}(\bar x_2)\psi_{\omega_1}(x_1)$, where $B_{\omega_1}(\bar x_2)$ denotes the coefficients of expansion of $\psi(x_1,\bar x_2)$ in the basis $\psi_{\omega_1}(x_1)$, implies that $B_{\omega_1}(\bar x_2)=\sum_{\omega_2}C_{\omega_1\omega_2}\psi_{\omega_2}(\bar x_2)$ and $f_{\omega_1}(x_1)=\psi_{\omega_1}(x_1).$ (continued in the next comment)

Comment: $C_{\omega_2}(\bar x_1)$ in Equation (1) denotes the same thing as $A_{\omega_2}(\bar x_1)=\sum_{\omega_1}C_{\omega_1\omega_2}\psi_{\omega_1}(\bar x_1)$, hence Equation (2). Bonus: Dropping the bar on $\bar x_2$, finally $\psi(x_1,x_2)=\sum_{\omega_1}\sum_{\omega_2}C_{\omega_1\omega_2}\psi_{\omega_1}(x_1)\psi_{\omega_2}(x_2)$, the same result from the tensor product of the two one-particle state spaces.

Comment: How does $\psi=\sum_{\omega_1}\sum_{\omega_2}C_{\omega_1\omega_2}\psi_{\omega_1\omega_2}(\bar x_1,x_2)=\sum_{\omega_2}A_{\omega_2}(\bar x_1)\psi_{\omega_2}(x_2)$ imply $ψω1ω2(x¯1,x2)=fω1(x¯1)ψω2(x2)$ at the start?

Comment: Expand the sum on both sides: $\sum_{\omega_1}C_{\omega_1\omega_2'}\psi_{\omega_1\omega_2'}(\bar x_1,x_2)+\sum_{\omega_1}C_{\omega_1\omega_2''}\psi_{\omega_1\omega_2''}(\bar x_1,x_2)+...=A_{\omega_2'}(\bar x_1)\psi_{\omega_2'}(x_2)+A_{\omega_2''}(\bar x_1)\psi_{\omega_2''}(x_2)+...$. Then $C_{\omega_1'\omega_2'}\psi_{\omega_1'\omega_2'}(\bar x_1,x_2)+C_{\omega_1''\omega_2'}\psi_{\omega_1''\omega_2'}(\bar x_1,x_2)+...=A_{\omega_2'}(\bar x_1)\psi_{\omega_2'}(x_2)$, which can be satisfied by (continued in the next comment)

Comment: letting $\psi_{\omega_1\omega_2}(\bar x_1,x_2)=f_{\omega_1}(\bar x_1)\psi_{\omega_2}(x_2)$ as shown: $C_{\omega_1'\omega_2'}f_{\omega_1'}(\bar x_1)\psi_{\omega_2'}(x_2)+C_{\omega_1''\omega_2'}f_{\omega_1''}(\bar x_1)\psi_{\omega_2'}(x_2)+...=[\sum_{\omega_1}C_{\omega_1\omega_2'}f_{\omega_1}(\bar x_1)]\psi_{\omega_2'}(x_2)$ so $A_{\omega_2'}(\bar x_1)=\sum_{\omega_1}C_{\omega_1\omega_2'}f_{\omega_1}(\bar x_1)$